# How to flip image with opencv and python( without cv2.flip)

Tags: python, opencv

i just want to flip image vertically without `cv2.flip()`, but output is completely black image. where is my mistake ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def flipv(imgg):
    for i in range(480):
        img2= np.zeros([480, 640, 3], np.uint8)
        img2[i,:]=imgg[480-i-1,:]

    return img2

img = cv2.imread("foto\\test.jpg", 1)

ads= flipv(img)

cv2.imshow("qw",ads)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code for flipping is correct (depends on how you want to perform your flip, but anyway) but you should create your img2 "outside" of your for loop only once.

```
def flipv(imgg):
    img2= np.zeros([480, 640, 3], np.uint8)
    for i in range(480):

        img2[i,:]=imgg[480-i-1,:]

    return img2
```

Comment: Updated my answer with flip function.

Answer (score 7):

Simple function to flip images using opencv:

```
def flip(img,axes):
    if (axes == 0) :
        #horizental flip
        return cv2.flip( img, 0 )
    elif(axes == 1):
        #vertical flip
        return cv2.flip( img, 1 )
    elif(axes == -1):
        #both direction
        return cv2.flip( img, -1 ) 
bflp = flip(img,-1)
plt.imshow(bflp)
```

Comment: Or you could just set `flip = cv2.flip`, without writing an additional wrapper on top of it :)

Comment: I think they're just explaining the function usage.

Answer (score 6):

You can use broadcasting of arrays as shown below. It is a lot faster:

```
cv2.imshow("flipped image", im[::-1])
```

Comment: interesting, but this does both H/V flip, +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy.flip:

```
flip_v = np.flip(img,0)
flip_h = np.flip(img,1)
```

s.a.: [numpy.flip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)